# Python unable to find Elasticsearch

Tags: python, python-2.7, elasticsearch

I am new to python and I am trying to experience with python and elasticsearch.

I installed python by installing homebrew and running:

```
brew install python
```

This also installed pip. Then when I had pip I ran:

```
pip install elasticsearch
```

This installed elasticsearch. However, When I run the script below:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

es = elasticsearch()

print("hello")
```

It tells me the following:

```
File "script.py", line 1, in <module>
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
ImportError: No module named elasticsearch
```

Can anyone offer any guidance as to what the issue is?

Comment: Can you add the result of this list command to your question: ls /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ ? Also would like to see the results of running "ls -l *.pyc" in the directory where script.pc resides.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `es = Elasticsearch()` instead of `es = elasticsearch()`?

Answer (score 7):

If you've installed through **pip**, set/export below environment variable--

```
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

For **pyCharm**, just add *PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages;* in *Environment variables*. You can reach to this setting by "Run-> Edit Configuration". Click apply and it should work fine.

Comment: i don't know why I've been looking for this answer all over the internet and by accident you've answered this pycharm thing for me. Thanks a million!!!!!

Comment: @cora Glad that it was helpful to you.:)

Comment: I think this is Windows solution right? What about Linux?

Comment: @Kourosh - This is for Mac. It should work for Linux too. Sorry for age old reply.

Answer (score 4):

You should capitalize the 'elasticsearch()'

Quoting from [es-python](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/python-api/current/)

```
# by default we connect to localhost:9200
es = Elasticsearch()
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that the python IDLE version in which you run the script is same as the version in which the pip installed elastic search. Sometimes you might run the script in the 3.x version and might have installed elastic search in 2.x version on the same machine.

Comment: How can I check the versions? By the way, I did not install this by pip. I didnt use pip but installed ES with an rpm on Centos.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I manage to fix the issue by adding in .bash_profile :

export PYTHONPATH=/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages

Answer (score 0):

go to Command prompt.

1. ***python -m*** pip install elasticsearch  (use python -m )
2. python
3. import elasticsearch