# Python(pip) not install ElasticSearch library on kubernetes

Tags: python, docker, elasticsearch, kubernetes, pip

I'm writing a python application to push some results onto `elasticsearch`.

I've written a `Dockerfile` to build it & am deploying it over `Kubernetes`.

Things seems to be working without any problem on my local machine, when I execute docker run.

The application is running and it is pushing data onto ElasticSearch.

But when I run it on K8S, I'm getting below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "application.py", line 2, in &lt;module&gt;
    from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'elasticsearch'
```

I'm installing elasticsearch, using `pip`.

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM python:3.7.3-alpine

RUN apk update && apk upgrade && apk add gcc libc-dev g++ libffi-dev libxml2 unixodbc-dev mariadb-dev postgresql-dev \
python-dev vim

RUN addgroup -S -g 1000 docker \
    && adduser -D -S -h /var/cache/docker -s /sbin/nologin -G docker -u 1000 docker \
    && chown docker:docker -R /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/

WORKDIR /app/
COPY application.py /app/
COPY lib.txt /app/
RUN chown docker:docker -R /app/

USER docker

# Install the dependencies
RUN ["pip", "install", "-r", "lib.txt", "--user"]

ENV PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages

RUN echo $PYTHONPATH

CMD [ "python",  "application.py"]
```

**lib.txt**

```
Flask==1.0.2
prometheus_client>=0.6.0
requests>=2.21.0
six>=1.12.0
# Elasticsearch 7.x
elasticsearch>=7.0.0,<8.0.0
pyodbc
```

As suggested in one [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40042834/926572), I'm also setting `PYTHONPATH` in `Dockerfile`.

Any suggestions, what am I missing?

Example code [here](https://github.com/raul8/pythonapp).

*Thanks*

Comment: Have you tried logging into the container(pod) and installing and executing `elasticsearch` manually? It could help you debug further.

Comment: Can you share a small snippet of your code I would like to check it?

Comment: @FL3SH, I've edited my question & added the repo.

Comment: It is working it both cases (docker, kubernetes) I see `__init__ called`. Please add your kubernetes yaml.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7.3-alpine

RUN apk update && apk upgrade && apk add gcc libc-dev g++ libffi-dev libxml2 unixodbc-dev mariadb-dev postgresql-dev \
python-dev vim

# Install the dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN mkdir /app
COPY lib.txt /app/lib.txt
RUN pip install -r lib.txt

RUN addgroup -S -g 1000 docker \
    && adduser -D -S -h /var/cache/docker -s /sbin/nologin -G docker -u 1000 docker

WORKDIR /app
COPY application.py /app/
RUN chown docker:docker -R /app/

USER docker

CMD [ "python",  "application.py"]
```

Changes:

- Updated pip before install dependencies. This remove some warnings into my containers, and keep pip package with the last version when building the image.
- Installed the pip packages as part of the system, when still root user is executing.
- Removed PYTHONPATH, which seems pointing to wrong place.
- Removed unnecessary owner changing.

Comment: It is giving error `no such option: -u` for pip install. I figured it must be `-U`